# Multidimensional dynamic array class using a continuous block of memory

Tags: c++, array, collections

The following code is designed to  be a multidimensional array that works off of a continuous block of memory. It is designed to be able to be resized at runtime, but only when a resize is explicitly requested.

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstddef>

namespace detail{
    //frame buffer class: represents a 2d array of audio data using a continuous block of memory
    template<typename T,template<typename...>class __frame_type>
    class __frame_buffer{
    public:
        using self_type = __frame_buffer<T,__frame_type>;
        using frame_type = __frame_type<T>;
        using value_type = T;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using const_pointer = const value_type*;
        using reference = value_type&;
        using const_reference = const value_type&;

        __frame_buffer():_data(),_frame_data(),_size(0),_frame_size(0){}

        __frame_buffer(size_type nframes,size_type fsize):_data(std::make_unique<value_type[]>(nframes*fsize)),
                                                          _frame_data(std::make_unique<frame_type[]>(nframes)),
                                                          _size(nframes),
                                                          _frame_size(fsize){
            for(size_type j=0; j < size(); ++j){
                _frame_data[j] = frame_type(&_data[j*frame_size()],frame_size());
            }
        }

        __frame_buffer(self_type& other):_data(std::make_unique<value_type[]>(other.data_size())),
                                         _frame_data(std::make_unique<frame_type[]>(other.size())),
                                         _size(other.size()),
                                         _frame_size(other.frame_size()){
            for(size_type j=0,i=0; j < size(), i < data_size(); ++j,++i){
                _data[i] = other._data[i];
                _frame_data[j] = frame_type(&_data[j*frame_size()],frame_size());
            }
        }

        __frame_buffer(self_type&& other):_data(std::move(other._data)),
                                          _frame_data(std::move(other._frame_data)),
                                          _size(other._size),
                                          _frame_size(other._frame_size){}

        self_type& operator=(self_type const& other){
            if(resize(other.size(),other.frame_size())){
                for(size_type j=0,i=0; j < size(), i < data_size(); ++j,++i){
                    _data[i] = other._data[i];
                    _frame_data[j] = frame_type(&_data[j*frame_size()],frame_size());
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        self_type& operator=(self_type&& other){
            std::swap(_size,other._size);
            std::swap(_frame_size,other._frame_size);
            std::swap(_data,other._data);
            std::swap(_frame_data,other._frame_data);
            return *this;
        }
        //array subscript operators
        frame_type& operator[](size_type const& index){
            return _frame_data[index];
        }
        frame_type const& operator[](size_type const& index)const{
            return _frame_data[index];
        }
        //get number of frames in the buffer (length)
        inline const size_type& size() const{
            return _size;
        }
        //get the size of each frame in the buffer(width)
        inline const size_type& frame_size()const{
            return _frame_size;
        }
        //get the overall number of elements in the buffer (length * width)
        inline size_type data_size()const{
            return size() * frame_size();
        }
        //resize the buffer to a new length & width
        bool resize(size_type const& nframes,size_type const& fsize){
            if(size() != nframes || frame_size() != fsize){
                std::unique_ptr<value_type[]> _new_data(std::make_unique<value_type[]>(nframes * fsize));
                std::unique_ptr<frame_type[]> _new_frame_data(std::make_unique<frame_type[]>(nframes));
                if(_new_data && _new_frame_data){
                    _size=nframes;
                    _frame_size = fsize;
                    std::swap(_data,_new_data);
                    std::swap(_frame_data,_new_frame_data);
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
        //iterators
        frame_type* begin(){
            return &_frame_data[0];
        }
        const frame_type* begin()const{
            return &_frame_data[0];
        }
        frame_type* end(){
            return &_frame_data[_size];
        }
        const frame_type* end()const{
            return &_frame_data[_size];
        }
    protected:
        //array of value_type objects
        std::unique_ptr<value_type[]> _data;
        //array of frames to be overlayed upon the _data to simulate multidimensional array
        std::unique_ptr<frame_type[]> _frame_data;
        size_type _size;
        size_type _frame_size;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class __frame{
    public:
        using self_type = __frame<T>;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using reference = T&;
        using const_reference = const T&;
        using pointer = T*;
        using const_pointer = const T*;

        __frame():_data(nullptr),_size(nullptr){}
        __frame(pointer addr,size_type const& size):_data(new (addr) value_type[size]),_size(&size){}
        __frame(self_type& other):_data(other._data),_size(&other._size){}
        __frame(self_type&& other):__frame(other){}

        self_type& operator=(self_type& other){
            _data = other._data;
            _size = other._size;
            return *this;
        }
        self_type& operator=(self_type&& other){
            std::swap(_size,other._size);
            std::swap(_data,other._data);
            return *this;
        }
        self_type& operator=(const_reference value){
            if(_data){
                for(size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i){
                    _data[i]=value;
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        reference operator[](size_type const& index){ return _data[index]; }

        const_reference operator[](size_type const& index)const{ return _data[index]; }

        pointer begin(){ return &_data[0]; }

        const_pointer begin()const{ return begin(); }

        pointer end(){ return &_data[*_size]; }

        const_pointer end()const{ return end(); }

        size_type size()const{ return *_size; }

    protected:
        pointer _data;
        const size_type* _size;
    };

}

namespace audio{
    template<typename T>
    using frame = detail::__frame<T>;

    template<typename T>
    using frame_buffer = detail::__frame_buffer<T,detail::__frame>;
}

#include <iostream>


int main(int agrc,char** argv){

    audio::frame_buffer<double> fbuff{16,2};
    int k=0;
    for(auto&& x: fbuff){
        for(auto&& y:x){
            y=k;
        }
        ++k;
    }
    for(auto&& x: fbuff){
        for(auto&& y:x){
            std::cout<<y<<"\t";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The actual code is broken up into a separate header file.
My original instinct was to use a std::vector under the hood but it is crucial to my design that it is not possible for the array to be resized without an explicit request. The array will be used for an audio application I am working on and it would be very costly to performance if a resize were to cause an allocation on the audio thread.

I would like to know if there is a more concise way to achieve what I am trying to do as well as any design considerations I should take into account?

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7ecf9a7e1a4ee77)

EDIT:This container is intended for use in a real-time audio environment. An important factor in the design is that no dynamic memory allocation can occur from use while being used on a real-time thread.

The intent of the design is to have a container that from the outside look like a 2d array and can be indexed as such `foo[0][0]` but is implemented in such a way that the stored data is contained within a continuous block of memory. The frame class represents a "frame" of audio data, a "frame" is a collection of audio samples each of which correspond to a channel of audio data.

Comment: It would be good if the code has some minimal API documentation. As it stands, it's not clear how it should be used, and hence hard to review. Btw, I have written my own multi-dimensional array adaptor (with `std::vector` under the hood), with rank a template parameter and supporting element access either via `arr[i][j][k]` (for 3D) or via `arr[multi_index]`.

Comment: Drop the whole `detail` namespace for the review (doesn't really change anything, and the extra indent makes it harder to read), also for readability bunch up all the one-line operator functions at the end of `frame`. Drop the `__` before the frame types, esp. since they're in a namespace on your end. Then the audio namespace isn't needed in the review as well.

Comment: @scottbb thx for the suggestion. done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points that come to mind immediately.

1. Your array is merely two-dimensional. This is *much* easier than a truly multidimensional array. Hence your question is misleading/wrong.
2. You must not use identifiers starting with a double underscore, such as `__frame`. These are reserved for internal use in standard library implementations. Any user code using such identifiers is ill-formed.
3. Your code is not generic, but specific for your application. What you really want is generic re-usable code of the form

   ```
   template<typename T
           ,typename A=std::allocator<T> >
   class Array2D { /* ... */ };
   ```
4. You should really try to use a `std::vector<>` under the hood, so that all the standard operations (copy, move, assignment) are easy to implement correctly and in an exception safe way. Your issue that this would allow resizing w/o explicit request is invalid, as you can avoid/disallow calls to any members of `std::vector` that would (under the hood) re-allocate/resize.
5. There is no need for an extra array (your `__frame_data`) to mimick the multidimensionality.
6. You should avoid unnecessary non-static members when a `static constexpr` member would do (i.e. `_frame_size`) and member functions that merely regurgitate such values (`frame_size()`).
7. Iterators represent an inherently linear model for the underlying data and are thererfore not natural for multi-dimensional objects. Hence, iterator support may be dropped.
8. You should add sufficient documentation (preferrably implicit for ease of maintenance, i.e. via appropriate variable names rather than via comments) so that any user (including yourself when you come back months/years later) can immediately understand the intent.

With these points in mind, a skeleton for such a 2D array could be as follows

```
template<typename T, typename A=std::allocator<T> >
class array2D : std::vector<T,A>
{
  using base = std::vector<T,A>;
public:
  // types
  using size_type = typename base::size_type;
  using value_type = typename base::value_type;  // etc for other types
  using pointer = typename base::pointer;

  struct row {                                   // used as return type of at()
    const pointer ptr;
    const size_type size;
    value_type      &operator[](size_type i)       { return ptr[i]; }
    value_type const&operator[](size_type i) const { return ptr[i]; }
    value_type      &at(size_type i)       { if(i>=size) throw std::out_of_range(); return ptr[i]; }
    value_type const&at(size_type i) const { if(i>=size) throw std::out_of_range(); return ptr[i]; }
  private:
    friend class array2D;
    row(pointer p, size_type s) : ptr(p), size(s) {}
  };

  // construction & assignment
  array2D() = default;
  array2D(array2D const&) = default;
  array2D&operator=(array2D const&) = default;
  array2D(array2D &&) = default;
  array2D&operator=(array2D &&) = default;

  explicit array2D(size_type dim0, size_type dim1)
  : base(dim0*dim1), _dims{{dim0,dim1}} {}
  explicit array2D(size_type dim0, size_type dim1, value_type const&fill)
  : base(dim0*dim1,fill), _dims{{dim0,dim1}} {}

  // data access
  size_type size(size_type dim) const
  { return _dims[dim]; }
  using base::size; 

  const value_type*operator[](size_type i) const
  { return base::data()+i*size(0); }
  value_type      *operator[](size_type i)
  { return base::data()+i*size(0); }

  const row at(size_type i) const
  {
    if(i>=size(0)) throw std::out_of_range();
    return {base::data()+i*size(0), size(1)};
  }
  row at(size_type i)
  {
    if(i>=size(0)) throw std::out_of_range();
    return {base::data()+i*size(0), size(1)};
  }

  // resize to new sizes; if sizes change, data are lost.
  void resize(size_type dim0, size_type dim1)
  {
    if(dim0!=_dims[0] || dim1!=_dims[1])
      base::clear();          // otherwise, the old data would be re-shuffled
    _dims={{dim0,dim1}};
    base::resize(dim0*dim1);
  }
private:
  size_type _dims[2] = {{0,0}};                 // size in dimension 0,1
};
```

If you don't like to inherit from a `std::vector`, you can use membership w/o affecting the design too much.

If you want to keep iterator support, then need an object similar to `array2D::row` to serve as an iterator over rows. Unlike `row`, it must allow its `ptr` member to be changed and must keep the array size in both dimensions. It needs `operator++` and `operator--` to increment/decrement its `ptr` member by `size(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

This review is for the `__frame<>` template class, but I'm sure you can apply some of the points I make here to your other class. Here's what I get from a brief look at that class.

## The `__frame<>` template class

- Identifiers with two leading underscores are reserved for C++ implementations. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/2296177
- There's no need to have a `self_type` alias; using `frame` inside the `frame<>` template class is synonymous with `frame<T>`.

Thus, this code:

```
frame( self_type& other );
```

Becomes:

```
frame( frame& other );
```

- Add some spacing and newlines to your code. It's hard to read code that is all mushed together in a single line. This is especially useful for other people who might have to deal with your code later (such as me, reviewing this).

This is hard to read:

```
__frame(pointer addr,size_type const& size):_data(new (addr) value_type[size]),_size(&size){}
```

This is easy to read:

```
frame( pointer addr, size_type const& size )
    : _data( new ( addr ) value_type[ size ] )
    , _size( &size )
{}
```

- Add some comments to your code. It's hard to review your code when people have to guess what the expected behaviour of your code is supposed to be. Is your copy constructor supposed to do a shallow copy?
- Use the standard algorithms; they're optimized/specialized to be quick and generalized and they provide explicit names for your operations.

This:

```
frame& operator=( const_reference value )
{
    if ( _data )
    {
        for ( size_type i = 0; i < size(); ++i )
        {
            _data[ i ] = value;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Becomes:

```
frame& operator=( const_reference value )
{
    if ( _data )
    {
        std::fill( begin(), end(), value );
    }
    return *this;
}
```

- Follow the standard's naming conventions where applicable. For example, the `const` functions that return a constant iterator are named `cbegin()` and `cend()`, but yours are simply overloads for `begin()` and `end()`.
- There's no need to index into `_data` only to then use the address-of operator.

These:

```
pointer begin() { return &_data[ 0 ]; } // equivalent to &( *( _data + 0 ) );
pointer end() { return &_data[ *_size ]; } // similar to above
```

Become these:

```
pointer begin() { return _data; }
pointer end() { return _data + *_size; }
```

- Nitpick - Inconsistent aliasing scheme. Example: Your `reference` alias is `T&` in the `frame<>` template class, but `value_type&` in your `frame_buffer<>` template class. Pick one and stick to it.
- Nitpick - Inconsistent type declarations. Example: Sometimes you use `const T&`, other times you use `T const&`. Pick one and stick to it.